# How to build a mobile app from Flex web app

Tags: arcgis-flex-api, flex, mobile

We have a Flex application based on ArcGIS flex API in the final stage of development and ready to move to testing/production. The application uses some map services and a complex GP tool. My boss wants a quick mobile app out of it. I have never worked with mobile app. I want to learn- what it takes to convert this application to mobile app- software, coding effort. Some useful links related to ESRI or Adobe will be helpful.

Thanks

Comment: Have you looked to the API Help pages? Start with their overview: http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/flex-api/samples/index.html#/Mobile_Samples_Overview/01nq0000006p000000/

Answer (score 1):

I used to work with Flex a lot. If you want to make an Android app, create a new project in Flash builder, but select a mobile app. You can then simply copy the code files from your desktop project (Adobe AIR i assume) into the the new mobile project. You should be then able to either use an emulator, or plugin an android device and test/debug directly on your device. 
You might need to remove some of the controls temporarily, because not all controls have mobile theme implementation (which is used by default on mobile project, because its performance optimized), but you can build the UI relatively quickly in the mobile theme.

The other thing is, if it makes sense to use this platform anyway, since its being discontinued. Actually... donated to opensource, but we all know Flash/Flex have little future now.

Also, despite i used a relatively powerful phone at the time (galaxy s2), the application felt laggy/choppy. A lot of effort has to be put into optimization if you want to achieve native app like performance.

Answer (score 0):

Checking out the ESRI Forums at forums.arcgis.com is a good start. They are patrolled by ESRI staff, and quality GIS peers. They should be able to get you started.